# elasticsearch: problema al consultar a un rango de tiempo definido

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-query

I would like to know if there is a way to define a time range as follows.

With a watcher I am looking for records with a certain message within a field. The problem is that I want it to find the records 72 hours after they have been entered.

this is my code:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "status": {
              "query": "process"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "estatus": {
              "query": "error"
            }
          }
        },
        {
         "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "now-72h",
              "time_zone": "-06:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that the query always returns records that match the "status" field but without respecting the range (i.e. it can bring even older/newer records). I understand that by placing *now* I specify the current day. That said, how can I configure it to only fetch records from -72 hours? thank you community.

Comment: Add range inside clausule in Filter Query.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `should` clause, it will match only any one of the condition and return result because by default `minimum_should_match` value is set to `1`.

You can move your condition which you need to compulsory match to `must` clause and optional you can keep to `should` clause.

Below query will compulsory match `date` condition and any of the condition from the `should` clause.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "now-72h",
              "time_zone": "-06:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "status": {
              "query": "process"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "estatus": {
              "query": "error"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `now-72h` will give you the recoreds which are created in last 72 hours.

Comment: Hello @sagar patel as you indicate the range gets all that have been created over the last 72 hours, but how to modify it to only get the records that have equal or more than 72 hours of creation without counting the new records that have this status ie without something like "now".
with this range I get all the records but today's records are included. Do you have any idea. Thanks my friend

Comment: You can do that just changing the `range` query. In my current answer, I have used `gte` and insted of that you can use `lte` and that will give you your expected result.